# How to have a chart transparent, when one of the chart overlaps over other?

Tags: highcharts

How to have chart transparent, when its overlaps with other chart?

[image: Current Chart]

In the image, how can I have the bar chart little transparent so even the line and sparea chart be shown as in the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2w8ar9xm/1/)

Link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8csqzjm/2/) of the example code :

Answer (score 0):

You can set the series color in rgba format:

```
    series: [
            ...,
        {
            "type": "column",
            "color": "rgba(139, 188, 33, 0.8)",
            ...
        }
    ]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5fuzg1x6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.color

Comment: Color of the chart can be changed to anything, its not necessarily the specified color.

Can't we achieve the same as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2w8ar9xm/1/) without the use of color property

Comment: Also there is not way of knowing which chart overlaps over the other

Comment: Hi @AbhishekGowda28, If you don't use the `zIndex` property, the last series is on top. Only the `area` series has the `fillOpacity` option, so using the color option is the simplest way. You can also experiment with zIndex: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L2er0vwz/